# Run python exe in raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyinstaller

I have a python script named `client.py` and I created an .exe file using pyinstaller in windows 10.

```
pyinstaller client.py
```

I want to run this .exe in Raspberry Pi 3. What should I do in order to do so?

Comment: why not just run the python file directly?

Comment: Not only does this create portability problems (almost-insurmountable ones, if your Windows box is on x86 rather than ARM), it's also creating an executable that's much slower to start than one that is not packing an interpreter and its dependencies into a single binary. "Slower" is not what you should be aiming for on a Pi. Why would you want to make these problems for yourself?

Comment: I am trying to make a final product. The script needs lot of libraries to be installed. I am trying to find a way to directly use it rather than spending lot of time setting up the libraries. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes, there are other ways. `setuptools`, `distutils`, etc let your Python module -- when packaged as an egg or wheel -- specify its own dependencies, so installing it with `pip` will download and install them automatically. To also handle native dependencies, you're looking at something like `nix` (indeed, I personally run NixOS, not Raspian, on my RPi hardware).

Answer (score 1):

2 ways:

1. Compile the code on the raspberry pi. PyInstaller supports Linux, and it works almost identically.
2. Use [wine](https://www.winehq.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to copy the client.py to the raspberry py, install any required pip modules and run via `python client.py`

.exe binaries typically are windows only... There are ways to emulate a Windows environment and run windows applications on a linux system but doing such is extremely heavy-handed and would tax a raspberry pi's limited resources.

Answer (score 0):

transfer your program to raspberry pi os.

then.
then save it in raspberry pi.

install pyinstaller by pip command

`pip install pyinstaller`.

then cd to that directory where file is stored.

then run

```
pyinstaller client.py
```